# TFS cannot access from Explorer since changed password?

Tags: tfs

I have downloaded the [TFS Power Tool 2011](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) and I love it. I had to change my Windows password and since, I can't log via the Explorer. When I right click on the folder, I have only the option "Reconnect to Server" and it fail everytime I try. I can connect to the repository via Visual Studio 11 with the Team Explorer, a popup came and I enter my new credential, all works. But, not in Explorer. How can I add my new credential with TFS Power Tool?

Comment: Faced the same issue a reboot will help or clear the cache from your local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit difficult for me to test this but try following the procedure in point 1 of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2008/11/10/common-oct-08-tfs-power-tools-questions.aspx for changing your credentials for connecting to the TFS server. It is possible you will need to reboot or at least log out and log in to restart the shell extension.

Comment: You were right... require to reboot... 2011 and have to reboot for this kind of stuff :P